# runtime difference : quick sort and binary search

Tags: python, big-o

I got a problem with what I learned.

## What I want to do

- write first list and sort it.
- write second list.
- define binary search.
- compare runtime of sorting list(built-in) and runtime of binary search.

input size : 1,000,000 (both of list).

## What is my problem

I learned big-O of quick sorting is n x log(n). and that of binary search is log(n). so, repeat binary search by n-times, then we might get similar runtime with quick sorting but it isn't.

## Code

*make first list*

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(low=-10000000, high=10000000, size=(1000000,))

with open('./1st_list.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(str(len(arr)) + '\n')
     for i in arr:
         f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

*make second list*

```
arr = np.random.randint(low=-10000000, high=10000000, size=(1000000,))

with open('./2nd_list.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(str(len(arr)) + '\n')
     for i in arr:
         f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

*define binary search*

```
def binary_search(
    arr: list, #sorted list
    target: int):    
    start, end = 0, len(arr)-1
    
    while(True):
        if start > end:
            return None

        mid = (start+end)//2
        if target == arr[mid]:
            return mid+1
        elif target > arr[mid]:
            start = mid+1
        else:
            end = mid-1
```

*load 1st_list*

```
start = time.time()
arr_1st = []
for _ in range(1000000):
    arr_1st.append(int(input().strip()))
arr_1st.sort()
time.time() - start
```

*load 2nd_list*

```
sys.stdin = open('./2nd_list.txt')
input = sys.stdin.readline

arr_2nd = []
for _ in range(1000000):
    arr_2nd.append(int(input().strip()))
```

*compute runtime*

```
import time

start = time.time()
for ele in arr_2nd:
    binary_search(arr_1st, ele)
time.time() - start
```

### result

***runtime***
*my local resource*

load 1st_list and sort : 0.5s.
compute runtime of binary search : 4.2s

I dont know why these is different.

thank you for detailed information.

Comment: The best sort algorithms run in O(n*log(n)) time.  Binary search runs in O(log(n)) time, but it requires a sorted array on which to perform the search.

Comment: Firstly, use a timing utility to time the code, something like `timeit`. Next, the time for sort includes the time to build the list, it shouldn't. Probably most importantly: big-Oh describes asymptotic behavior, not runtime for specific n. The basis of this comparison is flawed.

Comment: Also, average and best case time complexity of quicksort are O(n) = nlog(n), the worst case is O(n) = n^2. I think it's highly unlikely that the code generates the worst case input for quicksort, but it's yet another problem with this experiment.

Comment: Just saw something else: this code doesn't use quicksort. It appears to use Python's builtin sort which is [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), a hybrid of merge sort and insertion sort.

Comment: @woodyAnd I think it's great that after learning about the big O of an algorithm you go ahead and try to verify for yourself! Keep up that spirit, even if some comments may seem harsh...

Comment: @MichaelRuth I thought built-in sort is quick sorting but it isnt. thank you. the difference of runtimes is so huge nevertheless it can be similar. and is there fault in my thinking?

Comment: @TomKarzes arr_1st is sorted

Comment: Big-O basically says "what happens if N increases?", and not "how fast is my algorithm?". You can have two O(n log n) algorithm implementations with vastly different performance. Try to run your experiment with varying N and see if the relative performance varies as expected.

Comment: "the difference of runtimes is so huge nevertheless it can be similar. and is there fault in my thinking?" Timsort is great for illustrating the flaw in your reasoning. Timsort is a hybrid of insertion sort (O(n)=n^2) and merge sort (O(n)=nlog(n)). It uses insertion sort to sort small arrays because it is faster than merge sort for small inputs even though its asymptotic time complexity is worse.

Comment: There is another flaw here. The builtin `sort()` is highly optimized C, called by python. The `binary_search()` implementation is pure python. Even if the assumption that the runtime of 1 `sort()` == n `binary_search()`s was true, this code wouldn't be an accurate test. Keep thinking about, and experimenting with the things you learn. You certainly are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you. I should learn exactly how it woks. there is lots of my fault, and you guys kindly point it out.